# Jetpack Compose collectAsState() does not work with Flow combine()

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I want to load data from Firestore, and combine it with other data using Flow `combine()`

ViewModel:

```
private val userCurrentProject = MutableStateFlow("")

val projects = repository
        .listenToProject() //listening via Firestore snapshot listener, no problem here
        .combine(userCurrentProject) { projects, currentProjectName -> 
            // combine works and called normally
            projects.map { project ->
                project.apply {
                    isUserCurrentProject = name == currentProjectName
                }
            }
        }

fun setCurrentProject(projectName: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    userCurrentProject.emit(projectName)
}
```

Composables:

```
fun ProjectListScreen(navController: NavHostController, viewModel: ProjectsViewModel) {
    val projects by viewModel.projects.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())

    // This is where the problem started
    // Lazy column not updated when projects flow is emitting new value
    // Even Timber log does not called
    Timber.d("Projects : $projects")
    LazyColumn {
            items(projects) { project ->
                ProjectItem(project = project) {
                    currentlySelectedProject = project
                    scope.launch { bottomSheetState.show() }
                }
            }
    }
```

The `flow` is working normally, but the `state` never got updated, I don't know why. Maybe this is a problem with `collectAsState()`?

But the state is updated when I navigate to next screen (add new project screen), then press back (popBackStack)

NB: using `asLiveData()` with `observeAsState()` does not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally found the answer

The culprit is that a State of **custom object/class** behaves differently than a state of **primitives** (String, Int, etc.)

For a **State of object**, you need to use `copy()`

So I just changed this part of ViewModel

```
val projects = repository
        .listenProject()
        .combine(userCurrentProject) { projects, currentProjectName ->
            projects.map { project ->
                // use copy instead of apply
                val isCurrentProject = project.name == currentProjectName
                project.copy(isUserCurrentProject = isCurrentProject)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I was just about to,

Comment: It's not that the behaviors is different, it is the fact that the data is mutable. Your state has `var`s and you change them. So the issue is not related to compose. Even standard recycler view with DiffUtil will fail to reflect state changes. It will try to compare old and new states which are the same objects. If we want to achieve unidirectional data flow and have our UI render properly, we should make states immutable and use `copy()` for mutations.

Comment: @ntoskrnl yes, I forgot that we should only use immutable object in Compose.